# how to use android project library in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-library

I am new in android. I see a lot of android libraries out there like `github.com` but when I download them none of them are a `*.jar` file like this one:

[NumberProgressBar](https://github.com/daimajia/NumberProgressBar)

It seems that all these libraries are for android studio NOT eclipse (Am I correct? This is important).

My question is: How do I use these libraries in eclipse?

I tried to import the downloaded library as an android project and then mark it as "is library" and then add to my project, but that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downloaded it and add it as library project and everything looks fine. How do you do it, it's extremely simple. Let us know in which step you have a problem so we can figure out what is wrong.

Comment: i first extract the zip file, then imported it as a android project, but after importing the java files was not there in src/... ,

Comment: I will be appreciated if you tell me how exactly you imported and build the library.

Comment: There is no files in "src" directory but in another directory called java.

Comment: ye, i mean , src\main\java

Comment: import the library as Android Project to the eclipse. Go to properties and make it "as library". Change the build target, it was 1.5 when I added it, change it to something after 4.0. Then it should be working.

Comment: Ok, I just tried to run the demo app, and it seems like you need to do something extra to make it work in eclipse. I moved the package from under java folder to under "src" directly, so it looks more like an Eclipse project. Now it works.

Comment: i did what you said,and added the library to my project, it is in dependencies folder, but i cant import, com.daimajia.numberprogressbar.NumberProgressBar;

Comment: And don't forget the clean the project, to build it again.

Comment: Yes, I had the same problem. Move the folders under java to src -> main -> src, then it will work. let me know if it works after you try.

Comment: get the "com" folder completely, so it will have the same package name when move it to under src folder.

Comment: i managed to import it;import com.daimajia.numberprogressbar.NumberProgressBar;

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.daimajia.numberprogressbar.R$styleable

Comment: did you clean the project ? choose Project -> Clean, choose both of the projects, library and your project.

Comment: this is the only way to integrate libraries like this in eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

That library is designed to be built with Gradle for Android (with or without Android Studio), producing an AAR.

Eclipse does not have native AAR support. I have published a [recipe](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/03/consuming-aars-eclipse.html) and a [Ruby script](https://gist.github.com/commonsguy/a3a534ea28ef8a82a213) to convert an AAR into a library project that Eclipse can use, though I have not tested it much.

Or, you can download the source code and attempt to reorganize it into an Eclipse-style library project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build the library first.
For your example, read the [Readme](https://github.com/daimajia/NumberProgressBar/blob/master/README.md) file, section 'Build'.

Comment: but this 'Readme' is for android studio.