# How do you use ShowcaseView library in your android project which isnt based on gradle build?

Tags: android, eclipse

As the question suggests, my project isn't based on Maven/gradle or any build. I have an Android SDK (Eclipse) where I do all the coding. Unfortunately there was a statement in ShowcaseView github library that it supports only gradle build.

How does one use the library in cases like mine?

Am sorry Am new to Android and google search din't give me a proper answer.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049075/how-to-use-android-project-library-in-eclipse/25049173#25049173

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to reorganize things a little bit. The easiest way I've found is:

1. Download the source code from github or the zip file in their website
2. Create a new folder (i.e.: 'ShowcaseView') in a different place.
3. Go to `/library/main/src` and copy `AndroidManifest.xml` and `res` folder to the new `ShowcaseView` folder.
4. Copy the contents inside `/library/main/src/java` to a new folder `src` inside `ShowcaseView`
5. Open Eclipse, go to `File > New > Project... > Android Project from Existing Code` and select as Root Directory the `ShowcaseView` folder where you have copied java and resource files (maybe check 'Copy projects into workspace' if that's what you want).
6. Once the project is imported, right click on it > Properties... > Android, select Project Build Target: Android 4.4.2 (API Level 19) and check 'Is Library'

Now you will have a library project ready to be used from other Eclipse projects.